# Converting a delegate callback-based API to async

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have to use a library whose API looks something like this:

```
public void Connect();

...

public delegate void ConnectResultDelegate(bool succeeded, string msg);
public ConnectResultDelegate ConnectResultHandler;
```

After calling the `Connect()` method, the `ConnectResultHandler` callback delegate will get called.

The API exposes other methods that work in a similar "request-response" manner; I guess the reason for the delegates is that the methods interact with an external hardware device, and the response (delegate call) may not happen for many milliseconds.

I was hoping I Could wrap the API in some way that would allow me to use it in a more "sequential" manner that is more like async/await, along the lines of:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    _library.Connect();
    // Wait for notification that this has completed
    // Do something with the response passed to the delegate callback

    _library.Configure(...);
    // Wait for notification that this has completed
    // Do something with the response
    ..etc..
}
```

Thoughts? Refactoring the library itself is not an option.

There are one or two similar SO questions out there, but they differ in that their delegates are passed to the methods, rather than being separate properties, making it relatively easy to wrap in a Task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a *lot* of answers that show how to convert events or Begin/End async operations into tasks. That code though doesn't follow the conventions of either model. It's similar to the Event-based Async model [EAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap) without using an event. If you searched for event to task conversions, you'd find a lot of answers. Delegates arent' used for async operations though, as the convention before EAP was to sue the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm) or `Begin/End`.

The process process is still the same though. It's described in [Interop with Other Asynchronous Patterns and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types). 
In all cases, a TaskCompletionSource is used to create a Task that's signalled when an operation completes.

When the class follows the APM conventions, one can use the [TaskFactory.FromAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory-1.fromasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to convert a `Beging/End` pair into a task. `FromAsync` uses a [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) under the covers to return a Task that's signaled when the callback is called. The Interop doc example for this is `Stream.BeginRead` :

```
public static Task<int> ReadAsync(this Stream stream, 
                              byte[] buffer, int offset, 
                              int count)
{
    if (stream == null) 
       throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");

    return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginRead, 
                                   stream.EndRead, buffer, 
                                   offset, count, null);
}
```

Using delegates is similar to using events, which is also shown in the [interop article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap). Adapted to the question, it would look something like this :

```
public Task<bool> ConnectAsync(ThatService service)
{
    if (service==null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));

    var tcs=new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    service.ConnectResultHandler=(ok,msg)=>
    {
        if(ok)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(msg));
        }
    };

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This will allow you to use `ConnectAsync` in an `async` method, eg :

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    ...
    var ok=await ConnectAsync(_service);
    ...

}
```

If `msg` contains data on success, you could change `ConnectAsync` to :

```
public Task<string> ConnectAsync(ThatService service)
{
    if (service==null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));

    var tcs=new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    service.ConnectResultHandler=(ok,msg)=>
    {
        if(ok)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(msg);
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(msg));
        }
    };

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can change `ConnectAsync` into an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)  which will allow you to use it as if it were a method of your service class :

```
public static class MyServiceExtensions 
{
    public static Task<string> ConnectAsync(this ThatService service)
    {
        //Same as before
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    ...
    var msg=await _service.ConnectAsync();
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's great. The `ConnectAsync()` sample code is missing the call to the service method (`service.Connect()`), but otherwise this seems to be exactly what I was looking for thanks!